# Looking to scrape a website

Tags: web, screen-scraping

I am looking to scrape a website like yelp.com, to get a listing of all the bars they have there.
Are there any tools or scripts out there which would help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done work like this on Superpages and citySearch using [screen-scraper](http://www.screen-scraper.com/).  From there you can write your results to a CSV, database, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks I downloaded a trial version of the s/w.
The tutorial is very detailed too

Answer (score 8):

From a Python perspective

- [HTTPLib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) to automate the page downloads.
- [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing the HTML source to get the info you want.

Read [An Introduction to Compassionate Screen Scraping](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/10/an-introduction-to-compassionate-screenscraping/) for good tutorial to get you started that uses both tools.

Comment: Has anyone out here used heritrix?

Answer (score 2):

If you know Python, there the [pyQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) module that I find handy. Like jQuery, it lets you use enhanced CSS selectors to select DOM objects, I find it far easier than using a parser.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) -  its cross platform, been using this for years

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a scraper back in the dot-com era to suck info from a few e-commerce websites. I used perl and for each site had two tiers of code. The "discover" tier would parse and find lists of items and the "process" tier would read product pages and separate fields of data and feed them into a database.

From the looks of what you want to do I think rolling your own solution is probably the best approach as it's not really complicated. Use Perl or a similar interpreted language with good string processing and regex support.

Separating the pages is really easy. Forget about parse trees (I went that way and gave up on it), it's much easier and straightforward to manually identify the clumps of text of the template bordering each piece of info you want and put that on a regex to extract the data.

Put them on a list, hash, whatever and then do what you want with it.